# React Typewriter effect doesn't reset

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have created a typewriting effect with React and it works perfectly fine. However, when I change the language with i18n both texts don't have the same length and it keeps writing until both texts have the same length and  then it changes the language and starts the effect again.

How can I reset the input when the language has changed? How can I reset the input when the component has been destroyed?

I have recorded a [video](https://www.loom.com/share/31c821371dc54a4b9e775f35577e70e2)

I have the same issue when I change from one page to another, as both pages have different texts and they don't have the same length.

Here code of my component

```
export const ConsoleText = ({text, complete = false}) => {
    const [currentText, setCurrentText] = useState("");
    const translatedText = i18n.t(text);
    const index = useRef(0);
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!complete && currentText.length !== translatedText.length) {
            const timeOut = setTimeout(() => {
                setCurrentText((value) => value + translatedText.charAt(index.current));
                index.current++;
            }, 20);
            return () => {
                clearTimeout(timeOut);
            }
        } else {
            setCurrentText(translatedText);
        }
    }, [translatedText, currentText, complete]);
    return (
        <p className="console-text">
            {currentText}
        </p>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are telling react to do `setCurrentText(translatedText)` only when it is complete or when the compared text lengths are equal, so yes it continues to write until this moment.

To reset your text when `text` changes, try creating another `useEffect` that will reset your states :

```js
useEffect(() => {
  index.current = 0;
  setCurrentText('');
}, [text]);
```

Now, I actually did this exact same feature few days ago, here is my component if it can help you :

```js
import React from 'react';
import DOMPurify from 'dompurify';
import './text-writer.scss';

interface ITextWriterState {
    writtenText: string,
    index: number;
}

const TextWriter = ({ text, speed }: { text: string, speed: number }) => {
    const initialState = { writtenText: '', index: 0 };
    const sanitizer = DOMPurify.sanitize;

    const [state, setState] = React.useState<ITextWriterState>(initialState);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (state.index < text.length - 1) {
            const animKey = setInterval(() => {
                setState(state => {
                    if (state.index > text.length - 1) {
                        clearInterval(animKey);
                        return { ...state };
                    }
                    return {
                        writtenText: state.writtenText + text[state.index],
                        index: state.index + 1
                    };
                });
            }, speed);

            return () => clearInterval(animKey);
        }
    }, []);

    // Reset the state when the text is changed (Language change)
    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (text.length > 0) {
            setState(initialState);
        }
    }, [text])

    return <div className="text-writer-component"><span className="text" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: sanitizer(state.writtenText) }} /></div>
}

export default TextWriter;
```

The translation is made outside of the component so you can pass any kind of text to the component.

Comment: Hello again! Adding the second useEffect fix the problem when the page changes, however, when the language is changed the problem is the same. Do you have any idea? Thank you!

Comment: Okay I have added the language in the useEffect and now it works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're wecome :) Ok that's what I was gonna say, you added `translatedText` in the useEffect dependency array, right ?